# ¿poruqe no se inserta nada en mi base de datos en firebase?

Tags: firebase, reactjs

Aqui tengo la imagen con la base de datos vacia, ya realice ciertas operaciones y se supone que deberia haber algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte de codigo que no esta funcionando:

```js
   questionSubmit() 
    {
        firebase.database().ref('uSurvey/' + this.state.uid).set({
            studentName: this.state.studentName,
            answers: this.state.answers
        });

        this.setState({isSubmited: true});
    }
```

Comment: chequea tus reglas, que esten para usuarios no autenticados

Comment: me dice "Tus reglas de seguridad están definidas como públicas, por lo que cualquiera puede robar, modificar o borrar información de tu base de datos" eso esta bien verdad?

Comment: `service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Veríficaste que tus datos de conexión sean correctos?

Comment: Datos de conexion? donde verifico eso?

Comment: le puse realtime database pero aun asi no me aparece nada solo `u-survey-86e95: null`

Comment: aah si ya lo logre tenia que configurar las reglas, read and write ambas deben ser true jaja, gracias Victor Hugo.

Comment: digo gracias Gastón jaja igual gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo tus reglas en la base de datos deberian estar como `true`, tanto en **Read** como en **Write**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```